# False induction proof, where is the error?

Tags: proof-writing, induction, fake-proofs

I'm trying to find the error in this induction proof:

We want to prove that for all elements $a$ such that $a \in \mathbb{Z}^+$, that $a^2 \leq a$.

The base case is when $a = 1$, therefore $1^2 = 1$ and we know this is true.

The induction case:

Let $b \in \mathbb{Z}^+$. The induction hypothesis states that $b^2 \leq b$. Therefore, we have to show that $(b + 1)^2 \leq b + 1$.

$b^2 \leq b^2 + 2b = (b^2 + 2b + 1) - 1 = (b + 1)^2 - 1$

Since $(b + 1)^2 \leq b + 1$, we know that

$(b+1)^2 - 1 \leq (b + 1) - 1 = b$

Thus we conclude $b^2 \leq b$ by the induction hypothesis.

My thinking:

I know the proof forgot to specify that $b \geq 1$ in the induction step. I'm struggling to see how this matters downstream.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Yes, we have to show that $(b+1)^2\le b+1$, assuming $b^2\le b$.       You seemed to show the opposite ($b^2\le b$, assuming $(b+1)^2\le b+1$)

Comment: Quote: We want to prove that for all elements a such that $a∈Z+$, that $a^2≤a$. Whatt??

Comment: So you want to prove $(b+1)^2\leq b+1$, but you assume $(b+1)^2\leq b+1$... That's not allowed.

Comment: @vitamind OP is trying to find the error in the proof.

Comment: @DonThousand Okay phew

Comment: @LilianCrow You can do this!!  In a proper inductive proof, what do you *assume* in the Inductive Step, and what are you trying to *show*?  And what does this purported 'proof' do?

Comment: @Bram28 i'm assuming that $b^2 \leq b$ and I have to show that $(b+1)^2 \leq b + 1$

Comment: @LilianCrow Exactly! That's what you do in a proper inductive proof .... and in fact this 'proof' does this correctly when it says: "The induction hypothesis states that $b^2 \leq b$. Therefore, we have to show that $(b + 1)^2 \leq b + 1$."  .... but then what does this 'proof' actually end up doing? Look at the words 'Since ... ' and 'Thus we conclude ... '

Comment: You write "Since $(b+1)^2 \leq b+1$". We do not know that, that is what we want to prove. You cannot use a statement to prove the statement itself.

Comment: @Bram28 ahh I get it, we make an assumption to use in the proof but the "proof" actually just proves the assumption not what it intends to "prove"

Comment: @LilianCrow Yup!  It goes just the wrong way around ... in the middle of the proof it assumes what it needs to show, and in the end it ends up showing what the inductive step should be assuming :)  In short, it goes from the $b+1$ case to the $b$ case, but you need to go from the $b$ case to the $b+1$ case